# Sharepoint Quick Launch Issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to add dynamic link add in quick launch  my requirement is that

1) one list like topics and other is Chapter in chapter list i took look up of topics list
2)Now i want to add topic items as Heading Link in quick launch and chapters items are child link in quick launch based on Heading item...

Is this possible by programmatically??

if yes then tell me steps or any reference link
if not possible than any alternate ways to solve this issue?

Thanks In Advance............

Answer (score 0):

If I had that requirement, I would:

1. create a simple quick launch item called "View Table of Contents" in the siteactions.xml file.
2. when the user clicks on that item, a javascript function is run that opens a modal dialog with the table of contents rendered from a simple aspx page with a TOC webpart in it.
3. then the user would click a link in the dialog and be taken to the chapter